# C# RSACryptoServiceProvider - JWT RS256 Validation Fails

Tags: c#, .net, jwt, rsa, sha

(I've already been thru a lot of Stackoverflow/google results trying to find a fix for this.)

I am validating JWTs signed with **RS256** using the default C# JwtSecurityTokenHandler. In some cases, the validation fails when it shouldn't. Concretely, tokens from a given Authorization Server validate properly while tokens form another Authorization Server won't.

BUT... **Using the same JWTs and RSA Certificates on JWT.IO validates ALL the tokens succesfully**. This is the part that makes me believe that there's something wrong/unusual in the C# implementation. **I am also able to validate the same JWTs using the same Certificates using the oidc-client JavaScript library**. The one place where the validation sometimes fails is in C#.

I traced the error down to JwtSecurityTokenHandler's ValidateSignature method. Searching the original github code and googling about RSA, I came down with this bare-bone method which allows me to reproduce the problem in a plain console app:

```
static void ValidateJWT(string token, string modulus, string exponent)
{
    string tokenStr = token;
    JwtSecurityToken st = new JwtSecurityToken(tokenStr);
    string[] tokenParts = tokenStr.Split('.');

    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    rsa.ImportParameters(
        new RSAParameters()
        {
            Modulus = FromBase64Url(modulus),
            Exponent = FromBase64Url(exponent)
        });

    SHA256 sha256 = SHA256.Create();
    byte[] hash = sha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tokenParts[0] + '.' + tokenParts[1]));

    RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter rsaDeformatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter(rsa);
    rsaDeformatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA256");

    var valid = rsaDeformatter.VerifySignature(hash, FromBase64Url(tokenParts[2]));
    Console.WriteLine(valid); // sometimes false when it should be true
}

private static byte[] FromBase64Url(string base64Url)
{
    string padded = base64Url.Length % 4 == 0
        ? base64Url : base64Url + "====".Substring(base64Url.Length % 4);
    string base64 = padded.Replace("_", "/")
                            .Replace("-", "+");
    return Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
}
```

It is from that RSACryptoServiceProvider and using RSAKeys from here (https://gist.github.com/therightstuff/aa65356e95f8d0aae888e9f61aa29414) that I was able to Export the Public Key that allows me to validate JWTs **successfully** on JWT.IO.

```
string publicKey = RSAKeys.ExportPublicKey(rsa);
```

I can't provide actual JWTs to this post (they expire anyways), but does anyone knows of a crypto behavior specific to C# that could explain these validation errors, which don't happen in JavaScript nor on JWT.IO ?

And if so, any solution for this?

Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518#section-6.3.1.1

> Note that implementers have found that some cryptographic libraries
> prefix an extra zero-valued octet to the modulus representations they
> return, for instance, returning 257 octets for a 2048-bit key, rather
> than 256.  Implementations using such libraries will need to take
> care to omit the extra octet from the base64url-encoded
> representation.

In the case of one of the tokens you provided on a copy of this issue elsewhere, the decode of the modulus includes a prefixed 0x00 byte.  This causes downstream problems.  But you can fix their non-conformance.

```
byte[] modulusBytes = FromBase64Url(modulus);

if (modulusBytes[0] == 0)
{
    byte[] tmp = new byte[modulusBytes.Length - 1];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(modulusBytes, 1, tmp, 0, tmp.Length);
    modulusBytes = tmp;
}
```

It looks like RS256 treats the signature as opaque bytes, so it will encode it as-is.  So you probably don't need this correction (though it's where my investigation started):

```
byte[] sig = FromBase64Url(tokenParts[2]);

if (sig.Length < modulusBytes.Length)
{
    byte[] tmp = new byte[modulusBytes.Length];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(sig, 0, tmp, tmp.Length - sig.Length, sig.Length);
    sig = tmp;
}
```